# log4net errors not logging in umbraco log file

Tags: debugging, umbraco, log4net

I am using Umbraco 7.5.12.

I have a class which is supposed to log errors but the entries do not appear in umbraco log file.

Though message to admin sends well:

```
public class ErrorReporting
{
    private static readonly ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    public static void LogError(Exception ex, string messageIntro, string id = null)
    {
        Logger.Error(messageIntro, ex);

        Error adminErrorMessage = new Error();
        adminErrorMessage.Send(ex, id);
    }
}
```

The url of the log file seems to be set correctly:

```
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="App_Data\Logs\UmbracoTraceLog.%property{log4net:HostName}.txt" />
```

and umbraco logs its errors correctly.

`ErrorReporting` class is in a separate project which is referenced in the starting project anyway and above log file setting is obviously in the starting project but it shouldn't be the issue?

I checked log4net enabled settings:

```
        bool IsErrorEnabled = Logger.IsErrorEnabled;
        bool IsFatalEnabled = Logger.IsFatalEnabled;
        bool IsDebugEnabled = Logger.IsDebugEnabled;
        bool IsInfoEnabled = Logger.IsInfoEnabled;
        bool IsWarnEnabled = Logger.IsWarnEnabled;
```

and `IsDebugEnabled` is false. Can this be an issue?

Comment: Edit you also check log4net configuration file?  It 8s also possible to control the loglevel from there on a global (root) level. And maybe check the Appenders setup there. Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usally use the `Loghelper` located in `Umbraco.Core.Logging`

```
using Umbraco.Core.Logging;

public class ErrorReporting
{
    public static void LogError(Exception ex, string messageIntro, string id = null)
    {
        LogHelper.Error(typeof(ErrorReporting), messageIntro, ex);
        Error adminErrorMessage = new Error();
        adminErrorMessage.Send(ex, id);
    }
}
```

Some additional information can be found [here](https://24days.in/umbraco-cms/2013/log4net-in-umbraco/)

Answer (score 1):

`IsDebugEnabled` is probably false to stop `LogHelper.Debug` messages from spamming the log file (there's likely to be a lot of these in the Umbraco core). If `IsErrorEnabled` is true your error messages should be probably be showing.

I know it is recommended to use the `ILogger`, but I generally use the static Umbraco instance when logging:

```
try
{
    throw new Exception("Test.");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Umbraco.Core.Logging.LogHelper.Error(this.GetType(), "Test error log.", e);
}
```